# Adding New Data to JS multidimensional Object

Tags: javascript, object

I am using an object in my react-redux app in reducer file.The object is like as below

```
tradings: {
        'buy': {
            data: []
        },
        'sell': {
            data: []
        },
        'total': {
            data: []
        }
    },
```

So,whenever i get a new dataset i want to push it into data array of any object ,Suppose i got `buy` and data:`[time:234234, amount: 0.0123 ]`.So my new tradings object will look like this:

```
tradings: {
        'buy': {
            data: [[time:234234, amount: 0.0123 ], ....]
        },
        'sell': {
            data: []
        },
        'total': {
            data: []
        }
    },
```

How can i concat arrays into this array in object?

Comment: `array1.concat(array2)`  ?

Comment: `tradings.buy.data.push(yourData);` or `tradings[key].data.push(yourData);` where `key` is a string var

Comment: `[time:234234, amount: 0.0123 ]` is not a valid array in JS. It should be an object if you want key-value pairs like `{time:234234, amount: 0.0123 }`. Why not using `Array.push()` btw? Maybe with `switch/case` to act based on buy/sell type?

Comment: `push` can't be used here unless you make a copy before, as the question is related to redux you need to keep care of mutablity

Comment: @CodeManiac you're right. Maybe OP can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the object since it holds primitive values. `tradings.buy.data = [...tradings.buy.data, newData]` may help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following object:

```
tradings = {
        'buy': {
            data: []
        },
        'sell': {
            data: []
        },
        'total': {
            data: []
        }
    }
```

And your received data was:

```
data = {buy: {time:234234, amount: 0.0123 }}
```

You'll first need to grab the key in your `data` object and then push it to the desired array in your `tradings` object like the following:

```
key = Object.keys(data)[0];
tradings[key].data.push(data[key]);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hsvd5pk/

Comment: SO, from the next time?

Comment: This is a generalized solution that should work for all cases where the key does actually exist. Just make sure your data is structured correctly and this should always work. Check my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
tradings["buy"].data.push( YOUR ARRAY HERE )
```

to add arrays into that array,
or create the array somewhere and add it via javascript :

```
tradings["buy"].data =  YOUR ARRAY HERE
```